# Remove object from array if it also appears in JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am using this script to remove JSON objects from an array, which both appear within the array and another JSON object:

```js
var stageChildren = stage.sprites;
for (var i = 0; i < stageChildren.length; i++) {
    for (var x in mainMenu) {
        if (mainMenu[x] === stageChildren[i]) {
            console.log(x);
        }
    }
}
```

To make this more understandable, lets say I had two objects called: `object1` & `object2`.

Inside `object1`, there may be the same JSON object which also appears within `object2`. If that's the case, the object is removed from `object1`.

While this script works, I think it might have a huge impact on performance. Why? Well, there's about 50 separate objects within `stageChildren`, and 10 inside `mainMenu`. The script loops through the first object inside `stageChildren`, checks if that object is also inside `mainMenu` (by performing a `for` loop again), and moves onto the next 49 objects.

Is there a more optimized way of doing this?

Comment: [Don't confuse JavaScript and JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). **Do** read the description of the [tag:json] tag.

Comment: there probably is but you most likely shouldn't bother looking for it unless you want to run the code hundred times or more every second.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Comment: You can try something like this:  if (mainMenu.includes(stageChildren[i])) { //perform operation }

Comment: @Quentin [I'm referring to JSON as in this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp)

Comment: W3Schools is **garbage**. With the exception of one line ("Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null).") and the stand-alone example at the top, it is entirely talking about JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: @MohitKumar Thanks, I managed to use the `includes` function, as seen above (or [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/kzX5Eqbg))

Comment: @Nanoo Glad that I could help you.. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var index = 0;
var stageChildren = stage.sprites;
for (var x in mainMenu) {
    if (stageChildren.includes(mainMenu[x])) {
        const result = stageChildren.includes(mainMenu[x])
        var index = stageChildren.indexOf(result);
        stageChildren.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mainMenu` is the JSON object - so `includes()` will not work.

Comment: @Nanoo Oh if this is the case then you can check my edited answer now :)

Comment: Thanks, but how could I select that specific object from the `stageChildren` array? (In this case, I want to remove it)

Comment: @Nanoo Check my updated answer now, if it works.. if not, you can do little modification as per you needs and it would work..

Comment: `includes()` returns either true or false. So the script above doesn't make any logical sense.